# How to Get CMS page title by store in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7.0.2 and I need to display the title of CMS page in my store.
I have two stores, one is in English and the other is in French. 
To get the title of the CMS page I am using below code

```
$page = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load('legal');
```

Here 'legal' is my page identifier. I have created two pages in my admin panel having the same url key for english and french store having different page titles. But when I try to get the title using,

```
$pageTitle = $page->getTitle();
```

It always displays me the title of English CMS page.
I have also tried to load the page using,

```
$page = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load('legal');
```

without success. Any Idea??

Comment: How do you switch stores in frontend? Is the rest of your page translated corretly?

Comment: Everything is working fine except the page title. the content it fetches is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at `Mage_Cms_Helper_Page`. It explains how pages are rendered.

Instead of using `setStore()`, try `setStoreId()`:

```
Mage::getModel('cms/page')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load('legal');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating two pages for both store then

you must have to careful when you assign page to particular store.

Please check for both pages **it must be assign to only one store either a English OR French.**

These could be main issue to get your pages every time english if you assign both pages in english store.

Please double check from admin.

Hope you can understand my thoughts.

Comment: Thanks liyakat. I have double checked it. Both the pages are assigned to different stores. One is for french and one is for english.